# r remove elements from list in data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data frame that has list in it

```
Id    lists
1     5,2,3
2     2,3,4
```

I wanted to remove the element from list which is same as another column

```
Id    lists
1     5,2,3
2     3,4
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(your_data)` at the end of your question?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`.  Using `map2` from `purrr`, loop over the corresponding `list` column 'lists' with the 'Id' and get the elements that is not found in the 'Id' with `setdiff`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    mutate(lists = map2(lists, Id, setdiff))
#   Id   lists
#1  1 5, 2, 3
#2  2    3, 4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Id = 1:2, lists = list(c(5, 2, 3), c(2, 3, 4))), 
  row.names = c(NA, 
 -2L), class = "data.frame")
```